# Controlling Nifi read from 3 tables to merge content from all tables

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to read new table entries on 3 HBase tables (using GetHBase processor) and merge them together in single JSON. But each GetHBase processor runs as soon as new inserts happen on its respective tables. In the end after merging the content (using MergeContent processor), i get 3 JSON's for data of 3 tables separately. Is there a way to control the HBase reads and merge them only once all 3 tables get new data?

Answer (score 2):

If you schedule the three GetHBase processors on the same frequency, lets say every 5 mins, and start them at the same time, then they should all produce a flow file at a similar time. The only odd case might be if one them takes a lot longer to retrieve data from HBase, so you may want to ensure the scheduling period is longer than the longest expected retrieval from HBase.

Once they are all schedule on the same frequency, you can then set MergeContent to have a minimum group size of three, it should wait until seeing all three flow files.

It is not clear to me if you are asking about joining the records from three tables, or simply merging them. The above approach is about merging them and you will get one flow file where the content contains the content of the three incoming flow files one after another.